# How to create mongoengine filter query from fields listed as string rather DocumentFields

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am trying to write a function which can take all filter query as string and later I want to parse it and create respective filter query used in mongoengine. I tried using Q() but all this is not working with string.

Working:

```
return Q(Id__istartswith=value)
```

Not working:

```
_query = 'Id__istartswith=' + value
return Q(_query)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keyword expansion.

```
_query = {'Id__istartswith': value}
return Q(**_query)
```